# Get page and page data by slug. Strapi and Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, graphql, nuxt.js, strapi

I have Strapi, and Nuxt with Apollo.

> I get data using a dynamic query, but I can’t apply this data for the
>   title and meta description.

Now I get one page like this:

my query for product.gql

query Product($slug: String) {
  products(where: { slug: $slug }) {
    id
    slug
    name
    image {
      provider_metadata
    }
    description
 }
}

my page page for one product _slug.vue

```html
<template>
        <div
          class="flex flex-wrap pb-16"
          v-for="product in products"
          :key="product.slug"
        >
          <div v-if="product.image" class="w-1/2 flex items-center justify-center">
            <cld-image
              :publicId="product.image.provider_metadata.public_id"
              width="450"
              crop="scale"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="w-1/2">
            <p class="font-bold uppercase text-2xl pb-4">
              {{ product.category.name }} «{{ product.name }}»
            </p>
            <div
              class="pb-4"
              v-if="product.description"
              v-html="$md.render(product.description)"
            ></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </template>

    <script>
    import productQuery from '@/apollo/queries/product/product'
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          products: {},
          api_url: process.env.API_URL
        }
      },
      apollo: {
        products: {
          prefetch: true,
          query: productQuery,
          variables() {
            let params = this.$route.params
            return {
              slug: params.slug
            }
          }
        }
      },
      head() {
        return {
          // title: this.product.meta_title,
        }
      }
    }
    </script>
```

**How to apply this data to output in head()?**

Answer (score 0):

You havent defined "meta_title" anywhere, so that data simply does not exist.
You need to add a simple text field to your content model called "meta_title" and add it to your query so you can define what it needs to be.
That, or you simply use

```
head() {
        return {
          // title: this.product.name
        }
      }
```